# Why is ctrl+/ commenting the entire line in my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

Hi I am trying to place a comment right after a line in my code in a Jupyter notebook. I am using **`ctrl+/`** with my curser at the end of the line but it is commenting out the entire line instead of putting a **`#`** at the end of the line. It was working fine till two days ago.

I haven't changed any settings or anything else knowingly.

Comment: It seems like you may have had a bug prior. The keyboard shortcut is supposed to comment out the line the cursor is on, I've been using jupyter for 5 years and that's how it's always worked for me. Generally a key bind is used to combine multiple steps into one, like going to the start of the line and then placing a `#`. `ctrl+/` is the same number of keystrokes as `shift+3` so it wouldn't save you much.

Comment: Reinstall! Reinstall!